# Is it possible to detect when a user changes their username (not nickname) and sent a message to a specific channel when it is done?

Tags: discord.py

I'm a bit lost in what to do with this one, I have tried a couple of things but i can only get it to detect nickname changes within the server, which is not what i want

This is what I have:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.display_name != after.display_name:
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(162, 28, 29), title=f"Changed Username")
        embed.add_field(name='Current Name', value=before.display_name)
        embed.add_field(name='Old Name', value=after.display_name)
        channel = client.get_channel(----------)  
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is an event called [on_user_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update) here is the example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_user_update(before,after):
    if before.name != after.name:
```

Comment: god i feel so stupid.. i literally saw that in the docs aswell but i just didn't think lol

Comment: no problem, if it worked please approve it.

Comment: i had to wait 3 minutes. sorry about that